# Flutter drop-down value not changing in UI

Tags: flutter

I'm building a simple UI to show list of equipment for a selected category. For now, I've just hardcoded Lists and Maps but eventually the data will be coming from Firebase. The issue is with the drop-down list which I build dynamically based on number of categories. I observe different behaviour in dartpad and in my local browser mode. The dartpad is here: https://dartpad.dev/?id=3754f586870f7976d9321ebec34fbdde

Full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const SignUpApp());
}

class SignUpApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignUpApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => BrowseScreen(),
        '/welcome': (context) => const WelcomeScreen(),
        '/browse': (context) => BrowseScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class BrowseScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  BrowseScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<BrowseScreen> createState() => _BrowseScreenState();
}

class _BrowseScreenState extends State<BrowseScreen> {
  late final Future<List<EquipmentCategory>> categories;
  late final Future<List<Equipment>> matchingEquipment;
  late List<Equipment> equipment = [];
  String dropdownValue = '';

  //For local testing without Firebase
  final List<EquipmentCategory> equipmentCategories = [
        EquipmentCategory('1iyQmcbWIV6gNMk5PX9E', 'Lawn & Garden - motorised'),
        EquipmentCategory('ofYNwqKtvbctjiwETKOZ', 'Trailers'),
        EquipmentCategory('r5FSAIyIrinkr8m1TXTj', 'Lawn & Garden - manual'),
      ];

  final List<Equipment> trailerEquipmentList = [Equipment(id: 'd9A8qfHT8lKIzhUk55K5', name: 'Two-wheel trailer 900mm', categories: ['ofYNwqKtvbctjiwETKOZ'], photos:    ["https://media.prod.bunnings.com.au/api/public/content/c65c035a7c7b4a7282c3b5f3def5ec76?v=94a4edf7&t=w500dpr1"])];

  late final Map<String, List<Equipment>> equipmentByCategory = {
    'ofYNwqKtvbctjiwETKOZ': trailerEquipmentList,
    '1iyQmcbWIV6gNMk5PX9E': [],
    'r5FSAIyIrinkr8m1TXTj': []
  };

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('initState');
    categories = _fetchEquipmentCategories();
    dropdownValue = '1iyQmcbWIV6gNMk5PX9E';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: categories,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                // while data is loading:
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      valueColor:
                          new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue)),
                );
              } else {
                print("Refreshing");
                return Container(
                    color: CupertinoColors.white,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Column(children: [
                            DropdownButton<String>(
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                              elevation: 16,
                              style:
                                  const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                              underline: Container(
                                height: 2,
                                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                              ),
                              onChanged: (String? value) {
                                // This is called when the user selects an item.
                                setState(() async {
                                  dropdownValue = value!;
                                  print("Dropdown value: $dropdownValue");
                                  _fetchEquipment();
                                });
                              },
                              items: snapshot.data
                                  .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                      (EquipmentCategory value) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: value.id,
                                  child: Text(value.name),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                              value: dropdownValue,
                            ),
                            if(equipment.isNotEmpty)
                              Text('NOT EMPTY'),
                            if (equipment.isEmpty)
                              Text('EMPTY'),
                            Column(children: <Widget>[
                              // equipment.map<Text>((Equipment value) { return Text(e.name)}).toList()
                              for(var item in equipment) const Text(style: TextStyle(color:  Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)), 'ITEM')
                            ],)
                            
                          ])
                        ]));
              }
            }));
  }

  Future<List<EquipmentCategory>> _fetchEquipmentCategories() async {
    return Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      () => equipmentCategories,
    );
  }

  Future<List<Equipment>?> _fetchEquipment() async {
    equipment = equipmentByCategory[dropdownValue]!;
    print('Equipment by category length: ${equipment.length}');
    return Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      () => equipmentByCategory[dropdownValue],
    );
  }

  _printCategoriesValues() {
    print('_printCategoriesValues');
    categories.then((result) => {
          print(result.length),
          for (var cat in result) {print('Category: ${cat.name}')}
        });
  }

  _browseEquipment() {
    print('_browseEquipment');
  }
}

class EquipmentCategory {
  String id;
  String name;

  EquipmentCategory(this.id, this.name);
}

class Equipment {
  late String id;
  late String name;
  late List<String> categories;
  late List<String> photos;

  Equipment({required id, required name, required categories, required photos});

  factory Equipment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Equipment(
        id: json['id'],
        name: json['name'],
        categories: json['categories'],
        photos: json['photos']);
  }
}

class _WelcomeFormState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  @override
  State<WelcomeScreen> createState() => _WelcomeFormState();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: CupertinoColors.white,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          MyButton(
            text: 'Browse',
            icon: CupertinoIcons.search,
            callback: _showAvailableEquipmentScreen,
          ),
          MyButton(
            text: 'Return',
            icon: Icons.recycling,
            callback: () {},
          ),
          MyButton(
            text: 'Login',
            icon: Icons.login,
            callback: () {
              showCupertinoDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Hello, World!'),
                  actions: [
                    CupertinoDialogAction(
                      child: Text('Close'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showAvailableEquipmentScreen() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/browse');
  }
}

class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const WelcomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<WelcomeScreen> createState() => _WelcomeFormState();
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyButton({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.icon,
    required this.callback,
  });

  final String text;
  final IconData icon;
  final VoidCallback callback;

  final double buttonSize = 90;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      minSize: 0,
      onPressed: callback,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: const Color(0xFFEAEAEA),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 20,
          horizontal: 30,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: buttonSize,
                  height: buttonSize,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: CupertinoColors.black,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: buttonSize,
                  height: buttonSize,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: CupertinoColors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  child: Icon(
                    icon,
                    size: 60,
                    color: CupertinoColors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(
              text,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: CupertinoColors.black,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone please advise why the behavior is different between Dartpad and local browser? Thank you!

[image: App behavior in dartpad vs. local browser mode]

Comment: "I observe different behaviour in dartpad and in my local browser mode" -- What is the difference that you're experiencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run you above snippet, you'll see an error message:

```
The setState() method on _BrowseScreenState#71a49 was called with a closure or method that returned a Future. Maybe it is marked as "async".
Instead of performing asynchronous work inside a call to setState(), first execute the work (without updating the widget state), and then synchronously update the state inside a call to setState().
```

The error is clear, in your code:

```dart
onChanged: (String? value) {
  // This is called when the user selects an item.
  setState(() async {
    dropdownValue = value!;
    print("Dropdown value: $dropdownValue");
    _fetchEquipment();
  });
},
```

you're calling `async`
on `setState` which won't work.

Instead, what you should do, is, as the error states - *"first execute the work (without updating the widget state), and then synchronously update the state inside a call to setState()"*

Your code can look like this, (without the `async`):

```dart
setState(() {
    dropdownValue = value!;
  });
  dropdownValue = value!;
  print("Dropdown value: $dropdownValue");

  _fetchEquipment()
      .whenComplete(() => setState(() {}));
},
```